# How to upload multiple media files "image or video" for RESTFull API in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm working on RESTFul API Project in Larave 5.7, and I'm using postman to test my APIs, I'm trying to upload multiple images or videos but nothing work with me!
I tried this way, however, it never gets inside the foreach loop!
And I also tried to use allFiles instead of file but it gives me only one file (maybe the last selected one)!!

```
  foreach ($files as $file) {
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $check = in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);

        if($check) {
            foreach($request->fileName as $mediaFiles) {

                // save here
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['invalid_file_format'], 422);
        }

        return response()->json(['file_uploaded'], 200);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I was uploading the files in a wrong way with Postman! 
This is the correct way :D 
It's worked :D

Comment: thank you for answering your own question (and not just walking away)

Comment: does this work for multiple video and image upload in under one Id? If yes, Can I get the github.